# I am using LinqQ for the following code but it is not doing a proper sort

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using LINQ for the following code, but it's not doing a proper sort.

```
if (index == 0) {
  if (Incomplete_issue_model.Count < 1) {
   LblExistIssue.Hidden = false
  } else {
  tblCustomerIssueListView.Hidden = false
  Incomplete_issue_model = Incomplete_issue_model.OrderBy(d =>d.Issue_Date).ToList()
  tblCustomerIssueListView.Source = new CustomerIssueViewDataSource(Incomplete_issue_model, this)
  tblCustomerIssueListView.ReloadData()
  }
}
```

The date format is `dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss AM`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this piece of code

Comment: is Issue_Date a DateTime or a string?

Comment: I am trying to achieve all record date wise sorting @G.hakim

Comment: Issue_date Is a DateTime @Jason

Answer (score 0):

issueDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(issue_date, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

issue.issueDateTime = issueDateTime;

after that Doing Sorting

Incomplete_issue_model = Incomplete_issue_model.OrderByDescending(d => d.issueDateTime).ToList();